# Highlight marker from user input in leaflet - R Shiny

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, r-leaflet

I'm trying to highlight points in my map based on the user input slider. If the point falls within a certain date range, change the color, and if it doesn't, default it to black.

```
#server
    shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
   
        output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    
            leaflet() %>%
                addTiles()%>%
                addCircles(data=df,
                          # ~Longitude,
                          # ~Latitude,
                           group = "myMarkers",
                          label = ~htmlEscape(date))
        })
        
        observeEvent(input$selectVariable, {
        mydat$col_format<- ifelse(mydat$Date >= input$falltime[1] & mydat$Date <= input$falltime [2],'blue', 
    ifelse(mydat$Date >= input$springtime[1] & mydat$Date <= input$springtime [2], 'black',
    ifelse (mydat$Date, 'yellow')) )

            leafletProxy("myMap") %>%
                clearGroup("myMarkers") %>%
                addCircles(data = df[df$AnimlID == input$selectVariable, ],
                           #~ mydat$Longitd ,
                           #~ mydat$Latitud,
                           group = "myMarkers",
                           col = mydat$col_format,
                           label = ~htmlEscape(date)
                         )
        })
    })

#ui shinyUI(dashboardPage(#skin = "black",
    dashboardHeader(title = "Mapping Test", titleWidth = 350
),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 350,
        selectInput("selectVariable", label = h4("Select an D:"),
                                             choices =  unique(df$id)),
                   
                                 sliderInput("falltime","NSD Fall Slider:",
                                             min = min, max = max, value = c(min, max)),
                                verbatimTextOutput("dateText"),
                                 sliderInput("springtime","NSD Spring Slider:",
                                             min = min, max = max, value = c(min, max)),
                                 actionButton("submit", ("Submit"))),
    dashboardBody(fluidPage(
           box( plotOutput("plotlraj")),
           box( leafletOutput("myMap")),
           box(DT::dataTableOutput("Table"),
)
                
        ),
    )
))
```

With the above code I don't get any errors but the map is really slow to load and the points are always blue no matter what the date range the slider input is set to.

I've also tried adding this reactive block but again, all the points are blue even when I change the slider date range

```
    colorpal<- reactive({
    
        if(mydat$Date >= input$falltime[1] & mydat$Date <= input$falltime [2]){
            mydat[,'seasonColor']<-'#626262'
        }
        if(mydat$Date >= input$springtime[1] & mydat$Date <= input$springtime [2]){
            mydat[,'seasonColor']<-'#BAF218
'
        }
```

Comment: You need `ifelse` instead of `if/else` or use `case_when` as `if/else` is not vectorized

Comment: I would suggest to make a reactive data.frame. It would be dependent on `input$selectVariable`, `input$falltime`, and `input$springtime`. In the reactive function, you do your filtering by `AnimlID`, and based on the falltime and springtime values, create a factor column with the levels fall, spring, NA. And then `colorFactor()` on that column.

Comment: @rbasa Thanks for the suggestion. Do you think you could provide an example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `quakes` so others can replicate.

In the `filtered_df` reactive function, manipulate your data.frame as you prefer. I prefer using dplyr, but am showing base R.

`req()` are used to ensure those inputs have values.

There is no need to have `addCircles()` in the leaflet instantiation. The `observe` reactive will take care of displaying the circles once `filtered_df()` is ready and every time it is changed after that.

For brevity, showing just the server code.

```
    output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles()
    })
    
    filtered_df <- reactive({
        req(input$depth_slider,
            input$mag_slider)
        
        filtered_df <- quakes[quakes$depth <= input$depth_slider,]
        filtered_df[filtered_df$mag <= input$mag_slider, 'Strength'] <- 'Weak'
        filtered_df[filtered_df$mag > input$mag_slider, 'Strength'] <- 'Strong'
        return(filtered_df)
    })
    
    observe({
        filtered_df <- filtered_df()
        pal <- colorFactor(c('Green', 'Red'), domain = filtered_df$Strength)
        
        leafletProxy('myMap') %>%
            clearGroup('myMarkers') %>%
            clearControls() %>%
            addCircles(
                data = filtered_df,
                lng = ~long,
                lat = ~lat,
                group = 'myMarkers',
                color = ~pal(Strength)
            ) %>%
            addLegend(
                pal = pal,
                values = filtered_df$Strength
            )
    })
```